# subdomain on another ip address

Tags: redirect, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

My main domain (`example.com`) sits on a server with `IP address 1`.

I need to have a subdomain (`forum.example.com`) pointing to a server with `IP address 2`.

Both servers are hosted at iWeb, so I have a cPanel interface to manage them, but I can't find the right way to do that. I tried a `.htaccess` redirection, which works, but the visible address in the browser changes too.

Any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In common cPanel you can find the Simple DNS Zone Editor ! It allows you to enter Autoritative records for your domain name.

Redirects mysubdomain.mydomain.net to 128.128.12.12 :
[alt text http://img35.yfrog.com/img35/7479/screenshot20100406at020.png](http://img35.yfrog.com/img35/7479/screenshot20100406at020.png)

Comment: Thanks, that works! Now, right now, on server2, my account is http://IP_ADDRESS/~forum1/ . Do you know what do i have to do in cPanel so that forum.example.com points to the ~forum1/  folder?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with iWeb but you should just be able to set up another A record for forum.domain.com to point to the ip address 2.

i.e. you need to set this up in DNS.

Comment: +1, right answer. Shouldn't have anything to do with your host, only with your registrar.

Comment: thank you, your answer helped. I had to vote the other answer as the best one since it answered specifically for cpanel. I've +1-ed yours though.